# Trying to create dial tone frequency as a wav file

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, wav

I'm creating a program that takes in user input and generates the dial tone of a phone number, the expected user input should go something like this:

```
./a.exe wavename.wav 0.5 3456781234
```

I've gotten my code to the point where I generate the file but the file I get is corrupted and contains no sound.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BYTES_PER_SAMPLE 2
#define SAMPLE_RATE 44100
#define NUM_CHANNELS 1
#define AMPLITUDE 16382

void show_usage(void);

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    typedef struct 
    {
         uint8_t ChunkID[4];  
         uint32_t ChunkSize;      // 4 + (8+SubChunk1Size) + (8+SubChunk2Size)
         uint8_t Format[4];

         uint8_t SubChunk1ID[4];
         uint32_t SubChunk1Size;
   
         uint16_t AudioFormat;
         uint16_t NumChannels;
   
         uint32_t SampleRate;
         uint32_t ByteRate;       //SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
         uint16_t BlockAlign;     //NumChannles * BitsPerSample/8
         uint16_t BitsPerSample;

         uint8_t SubChunk2ID[4];
         uint32_t SubChunk2Size;  //NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
   
   
    }WAVEFILE;  
    FILE *pFile = NULL;
    uint16_t *pData;
    WAVEFILE myWavHeader;
    WAVEFILE *pWave = &myWavHeader;
    int16_t phoneLength = strlen(argv[3]);
    int freq1;
    int freq2;

    // check if user typed 4 arguments in the command line
    // using argc
    // if not, show user proper format
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        show_usage;        
        return -1;
    }


    // Check for valid numbers and symbols in phone number and tonelength
    // using argv[]
    // if not, show user proper format
    int phonenumber = atof(argv[3]);
    if (!(0 <= phonenumber <= 9 || '*' || '-' || '#'))
    {
        show_usage;       
        return -1; 
    }

    // change the string of the tone length to a numerical value
    int tone_length = atof(argv[2]);

    // check for valid tone lengths
    // if not, show user proper format
    if(0 < tone_length < 1.0)
    {
        printf("Everything good so far...");
    }
    else
    {
        show_usage;       
        return -1;
    }
    

    // Now, either a) declare a varible of WAVEFILE datatype to
    // hold the 'header' of the wavefile,
    // or b) allocate memory for the 'header' of the wavefile
    // using malloc()
    //headerPtr = malloc(sizeof(WAVEFILE));
    // and check it was properly allocated (did malloc return NULL?)

    // allocate memory for the data in the file (for the samples)
    // using malloc()
    
    pData = malloc(phoneLength*tone_length*SAMPLE_RATE*BYTES_PER_SAMPLE);
    
    // number of bytes will depend on:
    // 1) number of digits in number
    // 2) toneLength per digit
    // 3) SAMPLE_RATE - defined in wavefile.h
    // 4) BYTES_PER_SAMPLE - defined in wavefile.h

    // and check it was properly allocated (did malloc return NULL?)
    if(pData == NULL)
    {
        puts("Data not allocated in the file.");
    }
    
    pFile = malloc(sizeof(WAVEFILE));
    // fill in the wavefile-header structure (members) into the allocated memory,
    
    myWavHeader.ChunkID[0] = 'R';
    myWavHeader.ChunkID[1] = 'I';
    myWavHeader.ChunkID[2] = 'F';
    myWavHeader.ChunkID[3] = 'F';
    myWavHeader.Format[0] = 'W';
    myWavHeader.Format[1] = 'A';
    myWavHeader.Format[2] = 'V';
    myWavHeader.Format[3] = 'E';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk1ID[0] = 'f';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk1ID[1] = 'm';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk1ID[2] = 't';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk1ID[3] = ' ';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk1Size = 16;
    myWavHeader.AudioFormat = 1; 
    myWavHeader.NumChannels = 1;
    myWavHeader.SampleRate = 44100; 
    myWavHeader.BitsPerSample = 16;
    myWavHeader.SubChunk2ID[0] = 'd';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk2ID[1] = 'a';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk2ID[2] = 't';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk2ID[3] = 'a';
    myWavHeader.SubChunk2Size == (tone_length * *argv[2] * myWavHeader.SampleRate) *        myWavHeader.NumChannels * myWavHeader.BitsPerSample/8;
    myWavHeader.ChunkSize == 36 + (8 + myWavHeader.SubChunk1Size) + (8 + myWavHeader.SubChunk2Size);
    myWavHeader.ByteRate == myWavHeader.SampleRate * myWavHeader.NumChannels * myWavHeader.BitsPerSample/8;
    
    // open/create the file using fopen(), and check it was properly opened
    pFile = fopen(argv[1], "wb");
    if( pFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("File did not open.");
    }
    // create the data samples, populating the allocated data memory
    
    for(int16_t i = 0; i < phoneLength; i++)
    {
        switch(*(argv[3] + i))
        {
            case '1':
                freq1 = 1209;
                freq2 = 697;
                break;
            case '2':
                freq1 = 1336;
                freq2 = 697;
                break;
            case '3':
                freq1 = 1477;
                freq2 = 697;
                break;
            case '4':
                freq1 = 1209;
                freq2 = 770;
                break;
            case '5':
                freq1 = 1336;
                freq2 = 770;
                break;
            case '6':
                freq1 = 1477;
                freq2 = 770;
                break;
            case '7':
                freq1 = 1209;
                freq2 = 852;
                break;
            case '8':
                freq1 = 1336;
                freq2 = 852;
                break;
            case '9':
                freq1 = 1477;
                freq2 = 852;
                break;
            case '*':
                freq1 = 1209;
                freq2 = 941;
                break;
            case '0':
                freq1 = 1336;
                freq2 = 941;
                break;
            case '#':
                freq1 = 1477;
                freq2 = 941;
                break;
            default:
                freq1 = 0;
                freq2 = 0;
                break;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < (SAMPLE_RATE * tone_length); i++)
        {
            pData[i] = AMPLITUDE * ( 
                    sin(i * freq1 * 2 * 3.14159 / SAMPLE_RATE) + 
                    sin(i * freq2 * 2 * 3.14159 / SAMPLE_RATE)
            );
        }
    }

    // write (copy) the wavefile-header of the wavefile, from allocated
    // memory, into the file, and check it wrote properly
    int16_t header = fwrite(pWave, sizeof(WAVEFILE), 1, pFile);
    if( header != 1)
    {
        puts("File header was not allocated into the file.");
    }
    // write (copy) the data-samples of the wavefile, from allocated
    // memory, into the file, and check it wrote properly
    int16_t data = fwrite(pData, phoneLength*tone_length*SAMPLE_RATE*BYTES_PER_SAMPLE, 1, pFile);
    if(data != 1)
    {
        puts("Data was not allocated into the file.");
    }
    // close the file
    fclose(pFile);
  
    // free all allocated memory
    free(pData);
    return (0);


}




/******************************************************************************
* Function Name: show_usage
*
* Purpose: Shows user how to use this program
* 
* Arguments: None
*
* Returns: Nothing
*
******************************************************************************/
void show_usage(void)
{
   printf("\nUsage: ./dtmf.exe X Y Z\n\n");
   printf(" Where X is the name of the Wave file to create\n");
   printf(" Where Y is the duration (in seconds) of each dtmf tone, valid range is 0.1 - 1.0\n");
   printf(" Where Z is the string of digits to create tones for, valid\n");
   printf("    digits are 0-9, #, * and - for a duration of silence\n");
   printf("\nExample: ./dtmf.exe wavy.wav 0.3 123-3831\n");
}
```

Comment: you wrote `SubChunk2Size ==` instead of `SubChunk2Size =` and the next few lines also have this mistake

Comment: There are many issues. Compile with all warnings enabled and treat them as errors: https://godbolt.org/z/G6zrTqrxb

Comment: `show_usage;` does not call the function, `show_usage();` does.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).